# Can env-entry values from ejb-jar.xml be modified during runtime in Glassfish?

Tags: configuration, glassfish, ejb

My EJB project, packaged in an EAR, defines some env-entry configuration values in its ejb-jar.xml. I can inject these into my session bean fine.

I would like the possibility of modifying these values without redeploying, without modifying the descriptor (which should only contain default values) and without restarting the server. It seems like this is possible for web projects in Glassfish, using the `asadmin set-web-env-entry` command. I haven't found any equivalent for EJB/EAR applications. Can it be done?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same requirement in my current project

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. I have resorted to putting configuration values into Glassfish's global "Custom Resources" which I look up using JNDI. It doesn't feel like the right thing to do, however.